# EF7 throws ArgumentException after set_DeleteBehavior is called on certain machines

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Running this locally on Windows 10 runs fine, running it on Windows Server 2012 R2 throws the below exception.

Code is literally the same, after deployments didn't work I copied the local files to the server to validate.

I've looked around in the source on Github, hoping to find an answer, but have been unable to find any clue so far. Only thing that recently happened on the server is the installation of .NET 4.6, but the application was always already built for .NET 4.6 and only now starts throwing this exception. Reboot after .NET installation (just to be sure) also done.

```
public class Client
{
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Queue { get; set; }        
}

public class StatusUpdate
{
    public Guid StatusUpdateId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UtcDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }    
    public Client Client { get; set; }    
}

public class AccessLevel
{
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public int AccessLevelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedUtc { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class UserClientLink
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<AccessLevel>().HasKey(a => new {a.ClientId, a.AccessLevelId});
    //Set to -99 since value might range from -5 to max int. Enables inserts with the default sentinel value.
    modelBuilder.Entity<AccessLevel>().Property(p => p.AccessLevelId).Metadata.SentinelValue = -99;

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserClientLink>().HasKey(ucl => new {ucl.ClientId, ucl.UserId});
}

Context.StatusUpdates.Add(statusUpdate);
```

For reference, the complete strack trace.

```
System.ArgumentException: The value provided for argument 'value' must be a valid value of enum type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.IsDefined[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.ForeignKey.set_DeleteBehavior(Nullable`1 value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.CreateForeignKey(InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, String navigationToPrincipal, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, IReadOnlyList`1 principalProperties, Nullable`1 isUnique, Nullable`1 isRequired, Nullable`1 deleteBehavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.Relationship(InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, InternalEntityTypeBuilder dependentEntityTypeBuilder, String navigationToPrincipalName, String navigationToDependentName, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, IReadOnlyList`1 principalProperties, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 isUnique, Nullable`1 isRequired, Nullable`1 deleteBehavior, Boolean strictPrincipal, Func`2 onRelationshipAdding, Boolean runConventions)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.InternalRelationshipBuilder.ReplaceForeignKey(InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, InternalEntityTypeBuilder dependentEntityTypeBuilder, String navigationToPrincipalName, String navigationToDependentName, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, IReadOnlyList`1 principalProperties, Nullable`1 isUnique, Nullable`1 isRequired, Nullable`1 deleteBehavior, ForeignKeyAspect aspectsConfigured, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean runConventions)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.InternalRelationshipBuilder.ReplaceForeignKey(ForeignKeyAspect aspectsConfigured, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, InternalEntityTypeBuilder dependentEntityTypeBuilder, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, IReadOnlyList`1 principalProperties, Nullable`1 isUnique, Nullable`1 isRequired, Nullable`1 deleteBehavior, Boolean runConventions)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.InternalRelationshipBuilder.ForeignKey(IReadOnlyList`1 properties, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean runConventions)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ForeignKeyPropertyDiscoveryConvention.Apply(InternalRelationshipBuilder relationshipBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnForeignKeyAdded(InternalRelationshipBuilder relationshipBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.Relationship(InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, InternalEntityTypeBuilder dependentEntityTypeBuilder, String navigationToPrincipalName, String navigationToDependentName, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, IReadOnlyList`1 principalProperties, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 isUnique, Nullable`1 isRequired, Nullable`1 deleteBehavior, Boolean strictPrincipal, Func`2 onRelationshipAdding, Boolean runConventions)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.Relationship(InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, InternalEntityTypeBuilder dependentEntityTypeBuilder, String navigationToPrincipalName, String navigationToDependentName, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 isUnique, Boolean strictPrincipal)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.Relationship(InternalEntityTypeBuilder sourceBuilder, PropertyInfo navigationToTarget, PropertyInfo navigationToSource, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.MetadataDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(Func`1 getKey, Func`1 createKey, Func`2 createValue, Func`2 onNewKeyAdded, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.ModelBuilder.Entity(Type type)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.ModelSource.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.ThreadSafeDictionaryCache`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 factory)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at lambda_method(Closure , ServiceProvider )
   at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ServiceProvider )
   at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState, GraphBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.Add[TEntity](TEntity entity, GraphBehavior behavior)
   at Intreba.Enm.Server.Repository.ServerStorage.AddStatusUpdate(StatusUpdate statusUpdate, Boolean save) in C:\Development\Enterprise Net2 Manager\Intreba.Enm.Server.Repository\ServerStorage.cs:line 78
   at Intreba.Enm.Server.Repository.ServerStorage.AddStatusUpdate(StatusUpdate statusUpdate) in C:\Development\Enterprise Net2 Manager\Intreba.Enm.Server.Repository\ServerStorage.cs:line 73
   at Intreba.Enm.Server.Client.AliveHandler.Handle(Heartbeat message) in C:\Development\Enterprise Net2 Manager\Intreba.Enm.Server.Client\AliveHandler.cs:line 54
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry.Invoke(Object handler, Object message, Dictionary`2 dictionary) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\MessageHandlerRegistry.cs:line 124
   at NServiceBus.InvokeHandlersBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\InvokeHandlersBehavior.cs:line 23
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.cs:line 17
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.LoadHandlersBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\LoadHandlersBehavior.cs:line 45
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line 24
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.UnitOfWorkBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line 42
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ.OpenPublishChannelBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ef98ad7376e3379a\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\OpenPublishChannelBehavior.cs:line 19
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.ChildContainerBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\ChildContainerBehavior.cs:line 17
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
   at NServiceBus.ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Monitoring\ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.cs:line 23
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 52
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.Execute[T](BehaviorChain`1 pipelineAction, T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line 129
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 413
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMessage message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 344
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.TryProcess(TransportMessage message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 230
   at NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ.RabbitMqDequeueStrategy.ConsumeMessages(Object state) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ef98ad7376e3379a\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\RabbitMqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 193
```

Comment: The exception happens when creating the model. It seems there's something wrong with the mapping. Can you post the EF mapping configuration?

Comment: @FrancescCastells I added the OnModelCreating override (if that's what you're looking for), and also the two other entities that have foreign key's to the Client entity. Please note that this is not the entity that I'm adding at that point, I'm adding a StatusUpdate (which does have a relation to Client).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. EF is not even trying to add the StatusUpdate. The first time the context is used, EF creates an internal representation of the model structure. It seems to me that it can't correctly figure out how to handlle the cascade delete in one of the relationships. I would suggest you to fully specify the relationship between all entities, like modelBuilder.Entity<AccessLevel>().HasRequired(a=>a.Client).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a=>a.ClientId)willCascadeDelete(false);

Comment: Pfieuw, that's going to take some time. I'll report back. Any idea why it would be only on one machine?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I'm afraid I cannot assure you that what I am proposing will work either, but everything that you don't map explicitly is "guessed" by EF following some conventions and from experience the resulting mapping is not always what you would expect, therefore I always specify all relationships explicitly.

Comment: This did not seem to solve it. Locally the inserts kept working, reading from a webserver kept working, but on that one server the same error appeared.

Comment: We seem to work around this by running the application in x86 instead of x64 mode. In any case, we have the same problem.

Comment: Could it be an EF bug? I found this one which happened on x64 only too https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2451

Comment: I've just solved this by, not kidding, installing the 7 recommended and I don't know how many optional updates that were on that machine. Why, I have no idea, but perhaps you can confirm this @Max? Otherwise I'd suggest raising an issue at Entity Framework yourself (you can refer them to this post). Since this is now solved, I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to update the server and install all recommended and optional Windows Updates.